# Jsoup parse html

Tags: android, jsoup

I have the following situation:

```
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    <ul class="c d">
      <ul data-category="Z">
           <...some informations/>
      </ul>
      <ul data-category="G">
           <..some informations/>
      </ul>
   </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to store the value contain by data-category and everything that each ul data-category contains.
How to parse this?
I did:

```
String string_r=null;
Elements elems = doc.select("div.b");
for (Element div:elems){
   Elements div1 = div.select("ul.b c");
   for (Element vall1:div1){
      string_r=vall1.text();
   }
}
```

If I am printing the text values after the first for I receive a huge text with everything where div.b is found. But in this case the string is null. Can someone please help?
Thx

Answer (score 0):

You can try this tuts, It might help you to understand in parsing HTML [Click Here](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/example-list-links)

[Parsing DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12539647/jsoup-parsing-html-get-class-inside-class)